# Python requests: failed to get a certain url

Tags: python, python-requests

I opened debug info for `requests` and request an URL:

```
import logging
import requests

from http.client import HTTPConnection
HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True
requests.get('http://uae.souq.com/ae-ar/apple-iphone-7-with-facetime-32gb-4g-lte-gold-11526690/i/')
```

It outputs:

> DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP
>   connection (1): uae.souq.com send: b'GET
>   /ae-ar/apple-iphone-7-with-facetime-32gb-4g-lte-gold-11526690/i/
>   HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: uae.souq.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent:
>   python-requests/2.12.4\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding:
>   gzip, deflate\r\n\r\n' reply: 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently\r\n'
>   DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:http://uae.souq.com:80
>   "GET /ae-ar/apple-iphone-7-with-facetime-32gb-4g-lte-gold-11526690/i/
>   HTTP/1.1" 301 None
>   WARNING:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Failed to parse
>   headers
>   (url=http://uae.souq.com:80/ae-ar/apple-iphone-7-with-facetime-32gb-4g-lte-gold-11526690/i/):
>   [MissingHeaderBodySeparatorDefect()], unparsed data:
>   'Ø¹-Ù\x81Ù\x8aØ³-ØªØ§Ù\x8aÙ\x85-32-Ø¬Ù\x8aØ¬Ø§-Ø§Ù\x84Ø¬Ù\x8aÙ\x84-Ø§Ù\x84Ø±Ø§Ø¨Ø¹-Ø§Ù\x84-ØªÙ\x8a-Ø§Ù\x8a-Ø°Ù\x87Ø¨Ù\x8a-11526690/i/\r\nPragma:
>   no-cache\r\nServer: Apache\r\nStrict-Transport-Security:
>   max-age=0\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nX-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nContent-Length: 20\r\nDate:
>   Wed, 08 Mar 2017 16:20:30 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   PLATEFORMC=ae; expires=Thu, 08-Mar-2018 16:20:30 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=gdbudqf2d734i499du12qac0bofbjjvo; path=/; domain=.souq.com;
>   HttpOnly\r\nSet-Cookie: PLATEFORML=ar; expires=Thu, 08-Mar-2018
>   16:20:30 GMT; path=/; domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   c_Ident=14889900303248; expires=Sat, 06-Mar-2027 16:20:30 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie: registration_source=deleted;
>   expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie: registration_failed=deleted;
>   expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie: login_source=deleted; expires=Thu,
>   01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   login_failed=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie: BUYER_CITY_SELECTED=89; expires=Fri,
>   07-Apr-2017 16:20:30 GMT; path=/\r\nSet-Cookie: UserViews=11526690;
>   expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2017 16:20:30 GMT; path=/\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   NSC_tpvr-72.52.8.197-80=ffffffff2d81ae8345525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660;path=/;httponly\r\n\r\n' Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/Sona/work/projects/1688Crawler/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py",
>   line 403, in _make_request
>       assert_header_parsing(httplib_response.msg)   File "/Users/Sona/work/projects/1688Crawler/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/response.py",
>   line 66, in assert_header_parsing
>       raise HeaderParsingError(defects=defects, unparsed_data=unparsed_data)
>   requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.HeaderParsingError:
>   [MissingHeaderBodySeparatorDefect()], unparsed data:
>   'Ø¹-Ù\x81Ù\x8aØ³-ØªØ§Ù\x8aÙ\x85-32-Ø¬Ù\x8aØ¬Ø§-Ø§Ù\x84Ø¬Ù\x8aÙ\x84-Ø§Ù\x84Ø±Ø§Ø¨Ø¹-Ø§Ù\x84-ØªÙ\x8a-Ø§Ù\x8a-Ø°Ù\x87Ø¨Ù\x8a-11526690/i/\r\nPragma:
>   no-cache\r\nServer: Apache\r\nStrict-Transport-Security:
>   max-age=0\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nX-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff\r\nX-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\r\nContent-Length: 20\r\nDate:
>   Wed, 08 Mar 2017 16:20:30 GMT\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   PLATEFORMC=ae; expires=Thu, 08-Mar-2018 16:20:30 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=gdbudqf2d734i499du12qac0bofbjjvo; path=/; domain=.souq.com;
>   HttpOnly\r\nSet-Cookie: PLATEFORML=ar; expires=Thu, 08-Mar-2018
>   16:20:30 GMT; path=/; domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   c_Ident=14889900303248; expires=Sat, 06-Mar-2027 16:20:30 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie: registration_source=deleted;
>   expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie: registration_failed=deleted;
>   expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie: login_source=deleted; expires=Thu,
>   01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   login_failed=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/;
>   domain=.souq.com\r\nSet-Cookie: BUYER_CITY_SELECTED=89; expires=Fri,
>   07-Apr-2017 16:20:30 GMT; path=/\r\nSet-Cookie: UserViews=11526690;
>   expires=Fri, 07-Apr-2017 16:20:30 GMT; path=/\r\nSet-Cookie:
>   NSC_tpvr-72.52.8.197-80=ffffffff2d81ae8345525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660;path=/;httponly\r\n\r\n'

You can see it output a warning `Failed to parse headers` then it just hangs here.

I just want to get the response of that URL by request, what should I do?

ENV:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Aug 16 2016, 05:35:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)] on darwin

requests (2.12.4) Failed
requests (2.13.0) Failed
```

Comment: Looks like it's incorrectly parsing the `Location` header. Curl processes this request just fine.

Comment: did you try upgrading to the current version?

Comment: `curl` succeed to get that URL, but I'm want to use python instead...

Comment: @pvg Sorry, I mistook the result just now... It still gives that warning and hangs here after upgrading my `requests` to latest version.

Comment: "I think this issue might be related"(https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3098)

Comment: Curiously, I get a circular redirect (python 3.6, os x) and it works fine on python 2.7